# Listening for keyboard presses in OS X

Tags: macos, events, keyboard

I'm trying to write a simple launcher app for OS X. This means writing a background process that can listen for keys being pressed. How is this done in OS X? Can I install a listener somewhere, or can I poll the current state of the keyboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create a global keyboard shortcut for your app, use the HotKey API.  (Although the HotKey API is an old Carbon/CoreServices API, it is available to 64-bit Cocoa apps and is still fully supported and not deprecated in 10.8 Mountain Lion.)

[DDHotKey](https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey) is a nice Cocoa wrapper for the Carbon HotKey API.

To listen to all keystrokes from all apps, use [+[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsevent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask%3ahandler%3a); however, that is not the correct way to implement a launcher app.

Comment: The HotKey API sounds exactly like what I need, but I can't find any documentation on it at developer.apple.com. I guess I'd use LaunchServices to then open stuff based on triggered hotkeys?

Comment: Use DDHotKey, it's very simple to use.  The keycode and modifierFlags parameters come from the NSEvent that's triggered by a key-down event.  You can get those events by overriding -performKeyEquivalent: of a NSTextField.  Also see Events.h, which defines most key codes.  You can use [NSWorkspace openFile:] and [NSWorkspace openURL:] to simply launch an app, document, or URL.  No need to use LaunchServices.

Comment: It needs to be a Cocoa app.  A property in its Info.plist file determines whether the app is visible in the Dock or a hidden background app.